# Why does this user have only 301 reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[david-verhasselt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154399/david-verhasselt)

He has answered two questions (both are not community wiki) and received 56 up-votes for them, which should have given him a reputation of 560. He hasn't asked even a single question, so the probability of him offering reputation as a bounty is nil. Just out of curiosity, what happened to his 260 points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a *reputation cap* of 200 points per day. So after 20 upvotes on the same day, he did not gain any additional reputation.

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow/7238#7238):

> - A maximum of +200 reputation may be gained per day. Accepted answers are
>   immune to this cap ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/)) as
>   are bounties ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483019/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow)). This
>   immunity applies *only* to answers
>   accepted and bounties received *after*
>   reaching the cap.
>   *(A new day starts 0:00 UTC == 7pm EST == 4pm PST == 1am CET).*

Comment: EST for what country?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that option. Accepting this answer as per the FGITW rule :)

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/est.html ?

Comment: Or: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/au/est.html

Comment: Ah. Seeing that 0:00 UTC == 7pm EST, it must be the former.

Comment: There really should be a comma before "EST".

Answer (score 2):

The 56-vote question is a lot of votes for a low-volume post. Most likely, he received those votes very quickly so he hit his daily reputation cap (200 points per day) and didn't receive reputation points for every vote.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at his [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154399?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top), it seems like the poor chap was 'hit by' the daily reputation cap.

Comment: No votes for you.

Comment: He also got the reversal badge out of it